# Apache FlexJS download failed

Tags: apache, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flexjs

When trying to setup Apache FlexJS, I attempted to follow the setup instructions using Apache Flex Installer 3.0 on https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLEX/Using+FlexJS+with+Adobe+Flash+Builder. However, when choosing the Apache FlexJS Nightly option in the installer, Flash Version 14.0, and AIR version 14.0, it does not successfully install. It gets to about 50% downloaded and then it says the Google Closure Library Download Failed. Does anyone know why??? I am testing out FlexJS for converting ActionScript code to JavaScript/HTML5. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The installer does a MD5 check of all off the download pieces. Google Closure repentantly updated their library causing the MD5 check to fail. This has now been fixed in the Apache Flex Installer, just try again and it should work.